# My code has an error of inconsistent tabs and spaces in indention tried a few fixes nothing worked

Tags: python, indentation

Currently running my code in visual studio code and i have an error for inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in line 31 please see below and can anyone help have used 4 hours of my day trying to solve this error 
also i am coding in python and the error is where it is asking for the levels

def difficulty_level(user_level):
        level = ""

```
print "LEVELS: \t EASY \tMEDIUM \tHARD"
levels = ["easy", "medium", "hard"]
while level not in levels:
    level = raw_input("Pick a level: ").lower()
    if level == "easy":
        return question_easy, answers_list_easy
    elif level == "medium":
        return question_medium, answers_list_medium
    elif level == "hard":
        return question_hard, answers_list_hard
    else:
        print "Please enter a valid input."
```

Comment: It seems that the function's first line (`level = ""`) is indented by spaces while the rest is indented by tabs, but it's hard to tell exactly from a piece of copy-pasted code. Please turn on "display whitespace" in your editor (for vscode see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/18282) and inspect the whitespace at the beginning of the reported line (and it's surroundings) carefully.

Comment: yeah i have tried that too and nothin not sure what else could be the issue

Comment: Then, if you are allowed and willing to do so, make the whole file public (as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/), or upload it somewhere to a webserver, or to a public google drive folder, ... whatever) and I will tell you. This kind of whitespace issues is easy to hunt down, but not really suitable for being addressed on StackOverflow.